# Using Spring JPA Repository take in a List of strings and see if one of them is in a Row field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to set up a JPA query such that the repository method takes in a list of strings and include in the results rows in which a field contains on of these strings.

Here is an example object class:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class ExampleTable
{
    @Id // Assume id generation
    Integer id;

    @Column(length=400)
    String tags;

    // Assume Constructors, getters and setters are present
}
```

and here is an example Repository, comparable to what I tried to do

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleClassRepo extends JpaRepository<ExampleClass, Integer>
{
    @Query("select ec from ExampleClass ec where ec.tags contains in :terms")
    List<ExampleClass> getExampleClassesByTerms(@Param("terms") List<String> terms);
}
```

Basically, if the *tags* contains one of the strings in *terms*, that ExampleClass object is included in the list that is returned.

However, launching the spring boot application gets error messages like

```
2021-01-06 11:21:46.487 ERROR 21944 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:92: unexpected token: contains
2021-01-06 11:21:46.494 ERROR 21944 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:92: unexpected token: contains

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: contains
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:864) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar!/:5.4.25.Final]
...
```

Is there a better way to pull off what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the "contains" keyword is correct. Only "IN" clause is sufficient

```
SELECT ec FROM ExampleClass ec WHERE ec.tags in :terms
```

Also you can try out this method, without using "@Query". Spring data would understand it

```
List<ExampleClass> findByTagsIn(List<String> terms)
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work? My impression of the IN clause alone is it would check if "tags" is in one of the "terms", not if one of the "terms" is in "tags".

Comment: I'm sorry but correct me if I'm wrong. The condition is to check whether a tag is in the terms list right ? If so, the above will hold good

Comment: I'm trying to to the latter (the vice versa)